# convert domelement to string in php

Tags: php, dom

i have done a curl request and got what i needed in $resp.

this is my code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($resp);
foreach($dom->getElementsByTagName('img') as $image) {
        $image->getAttribute('src');
        if strcmp( $image, "images/Balls/"){
             echo substr($image, -6,-7);
        }
        echo "<br />";}
```

this does not work because $image is not a string... how can i make this code work? All i need to do is to convert $image to string.
Thanks in advance

Comment: line `$image->getAttribute('src');` - what it is supposed to do?

Comment: @Lashane get the attribute src of the html tag name img

Comment: get into what variable?

Comment: $image which is a dom element @Lashane

Comment: no, it is not how method call work, it goes nowhere, you should assign result somewhere, preferable avoid variable $image overwriting

Comment: i tried to assign it to a variable but it didn't work. i need it's type to be a string so i can compare it. adding for example $a = $image; echo $a; to the code won't change anything. $a won't be a string @Lashane

Comment: probably you should start with basic php syntax, you need `$a=$image->getAttribute('src');` and then use $a futher

Comment: well, it does not change anything @Lashane. all i need is a conversion of a dom element to string. that will solve the problem

Comment: what is printed by `var_dump($image->getAttribute('src'));`?

Comment: string(19) "images/Balls/06.png" 
string(19) "images/Balls/16.png" 
string(19) "images/Balls/17.png" 
string(19) "images/Balls/21.png" 
string(19) "images/Balls/35.png" 
string(19) "images/Balls/39.png" 
string(19) "images/Balls/34.png" @Lashane

Comment: so, if you assign result to variable - it will be string, as proved by var_dump

Comment: you need `( )` around condition in if, also - strcmp does not do what you think, it will compare full strings, not parts

Comment: i am an idiot for missing the (). Thank your for your time Mr.@Lashane.

Answer (score 0):

You're not doing anything with `$image->getAttribute()` except just calling it. You need to assign the result of `$image->getAttribute()` to a variable, and then pass that variable to `strcmp()`.

Comment: If you still need help, which it appears that you do, please help us help you by telling us what you tried, what the output was. "It did not work" does not help in the *slightest*.

Did you see an error? If so, what was it? Do you have `error_reporting` set to `E_ALL` and `display_errors` set to "on" in your php,ini?

So in this case, show what your errors are and what the `getAttribute()` line and the line containing `strcmp()` look like.

Also, why did you pick `strcmp()`? Try using `stristr()` instead. (Look it up on php.net to see what it's doing)

Comment: i want to say thank you. i tried assigning the result of $image->getAttribute() to a variable and got this error (Catchable fatal error: Object of class DOMElement could not be converted to string in C:\xampp\htdocs\testParse\test.php on line 22). the src attribute contains images/Balls/31.png all i want is the number 31 that's why i used strcmp . Howerver $image is not a string, even when assigning it to a variable.

Comment: > Howerver $image is not a string, even when assigning it to a variable.

Not what I meant:

`$src = $image->getAttribute('src');
if (strcmp($src, 'images/Balls/'));`